# How to: Disable trackpad entirely (NOT only when a external mouse is connected)

Tags: macos, hardware, trackpad

### *MBP mid-2012 - OSX HiSierra - 10.13*

---

### For context...I'll answer the first question most of you will (should) have.

**Why would I *ever* want to do this? I want to have ZERO access to a mouse of any type**???

**Reason**: I want to become MUCH less dependent on using my mouse to navigate in general. I have a USB mouse that I use 100% of the time now and I'm sick of it. It's a strain on my wrist, accuracy, and efficiency in general.

Having no access to a mouse is obviously the best way to do this. So, I'm going to disable the mouse entirely (before you go there....yes, temporarily [I mean, duh.]).

**And, now to the question...**

Is there a way to disable the track pad from a software standpoint? **I understand ejecting the ribbon cable is the easiest/apparent option**.

Any others? I'd rather not mess with hardware too much, even though it's entirely harmless if done properly. I'm guessing that will be my route to take here. But any chance that a few commands and/or editing/backing up files/drivers will do the trick?

Thanks guys and gals.

Comment: Please read my post before you mark duplicate. It's right in the headline.
 "....(NOT.............."

Comment: Don't want to be a dick, but wouldnt posting the link to that answer: a. take just as much time as posting duplicate. - b. be much more helpful/clear. c. Avoid disrupting answers to the question I have?

It's not just you. The whole community has made it a habbit so I get it. But something to keep in mind?

Also, the accepted answer was strictly regarding the keyboard, not mouse/